# Multiple Apache Virtual Host Files with one Document root?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I've set up a single VPS running Apache, with an application installed in /var/www/html/. I have a domain [example-1.com] to the server IP.

I'd also like the same application to be served on [example-2.com]. Something similar to creating an 'Alias' domain.

Is it possible to have two Virtual Host Files configured at one document root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, no problem. The document roots can point wherever you want them to. If the configuration of the second virtualhost is the same, you could also use the [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive.